# Regular expression for XML

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to build a regular expression that will match against the contents of an XML element containing some un-encoded data. Eg:

```
<myElement><![CDATA[<p>The <a href="http://blah"> draft </p>]]></myElement>
```

Usually in this circumstance I'd use

```
[^<]*
```

to match everything up to the less than sign but this isn't working in this case. I've also tried this unsuccessfully:

```
[^(</myElement>)]*
```

I'm using Groovy, i.e. Java.

Comment: Wait for it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Haha, thanks BoltClock.... "asking regexes to parse arbitrary HTML is like asking Paris Hilton to write an operating system"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please don't do this*, but you're probably looking for:

```
<myElement>(.*?)</myElement>
```

This won't work if `<myElement>` (or the closing tag) can appear in the CDATA. It won't work if the XML is malformed. It also won't work with nested `<myElement>`s. And the list goes on...

The proper solution is to **use a real XML parser**.

Your `[^(</myElement>)]*` regex was saying: match any number of characters that are not in the set `(`, `<`, `/`, `m`, etc., which is clearly not what you intended. You cannot place a group within a character class in order for it to be treated atomically -- the characters will always be treated as a set (with `(` and `)` being literal characters, too).

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing it on a line by line basis, this will match the inside if your example:

```
>(.*)</
```

returns: `<![CDATA[<p>The <a href="http://blah"> draft </p>]]>`

Probably use it something like this:

```
subjectString = '<myElement><![CDATA[<p>The <a href="http://blah"> draft </p>]]></myElement>';
Matcher regexMatcher = subjectString =~ ">(.*)</"
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```